# Question on the Fourier Transform, specifically concerning polynomials

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, definite-integrals

Suppose $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ with distinct roots, none lying on the real axis.

Calculate:

$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2 \pi i x \xi}}{P(x)}dx,\space \space \space\xi \in \mathbb R$$

in terms of the roots of $P$. What happens with several roots coincide?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? This is just a reformulation of the second case of its application to real integrals.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that. Just having trouble working out the sum of the residues at each pole. (I'm using the idea that the zeros of $P$ will be the poles of the function to be integrated)

Comment: You have to distinguish the cases $ξ>0$ and $ξ<0$ to select the correct half-plane. Then use $P(x)-P(y)=(x-y)\cdot Q(x,y)$ with $Q(x,x)=P'(x)$.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use that last part (since I'm not sure where $y$ comes in). Sorry, I'm really not great with complex integration :/

Comment: The integrand can be rewritten as $\frac{f(z)}{z-z_k}$ where $z_k$ is a root, and $f(z)=\frac{e^{−2πizξ}}{Q(z,z_k)}$. The value at the center, $f(z_k)=\frac{e^{−2πiz_kξ}}{P'(z_k)}$, is then the residuum at $z_k$.

Comment: I get that part now but how do I sum all those residues together? Is there a formula I can use?

Comment: No, in general there is no closed formula (that I'm aware of). The sum of residues is as far as it gets.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it now :D When several roots coincide, can you just treat coinciding roots as simple poles of order $m$? (where $m$ is the number of coinciding roots)

Comment: Yes. One has to keep in mind that the exponential is part of the function with the root.